# C# Regular Expression Matches

Tags: c#, regex

I am writing a function to get the matches from an input string in which I need to extract the matches.

**Input samples:**

```
1) QUO-{RANDSTRING:5}-{DATETIMEUTC:yyyy}
2) {RANDSTRING:2}-{RANDNUMBER:4}
3) PREFIX-{RANDSTRING:2}-ANY-TEXT-{RANDNUMBER:4}-SUFFIX
```

The input can be anything like the example above. The text outside the {} can be anything. The text within {} is the relevant part.

So, the regular expression should extract the matches as follow:

```
Input: QUO-{RANDSTRING:5}-{DATETIMEUTC:yyyy}
Matches: RANDSTRING and DATETIMEUTC

Input: {RANDSTRING:2}-{RANDNUMBER:4}
Matches: RANDSTRING and RANDNUMBER

Input: PREFIX-{RANDSTRING:2}-ANY-TEXT-{RANDNUMBER:4}-SUFFIX
Matches: RANDSTRING and RANDNUMBER
```

Comment: So every sequence of letters between `{` and `:`?

Comment: What's the `:5`, `:2` etc?

Comment: the numbers after the ":", means the number of characters and the letter after ":" means the format pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want every sequence of upper-case letters between `{` and `:`.

```
Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<={)[A-Z]+(?=:)")
```

Explanation:

- `(?<={)` looks for a `{` before the match
- `[A-Z]+` matches at least one upper-case letter
- `(?=:)` looks for a `:` after the match

Comment: Hi Klaus, it worked perfect fine! One more question, if I want to have RANDSTRING:5 as a matched value instead, how the regex would looks like?

Comment: @Andre - What do you mean by "matched as a value"?

Comment: So everything between `{` and `}`? Just replace the `:` by a `}`

Comment: @KlausGütter,
Yes, everything between { and }, but it didnt work as you suggested.

(?<={)[A-Z]+(?=})

Comment: Try replacing `[A-Z]`+ by `[\w:]+` which will not only match upper-case letters, but any "word character" plus the colon.